# How to merge dataframes of unequal length based on time with buffer intervals in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time, merge, intervals

I am trying to merge two `dataframes` where the common denominator is time. However, time records can differ between the two. I want to merge the two by time but with a buffer interval of 30 minutes.

### The `dataframes` are conceptually set up as this:

```
Data_cam <- data.frame(Start_haul=c(("31-10-2015  07:13:00"),("31-10-2015  22:40:00"),("01-11-2015  06:48:00"),("01-11-2015  16:13:00")), 
              VesselID=c('XBBX','XBBX','XAAX','XAAX'),
              Species=("TOR"), Discard=c(0.28,0.96,2.92,0)) 

Data_sif <- data.frame(Start_haul=c(("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  16:11:00")),             VesselID=c('XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX'),Species=("TOR"), Size_class=c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","4","5"),  Landing_kg=c(10.5,20.5,5.6,400,2,120,250,10.3,2.1))
```

---

This mean that the three first rows in Data_sif match the first row in Data_cam and I want to add the column "Discard"-value from the first row in Data_cam onto the three first rows in Data_sif.
Likewise, the 4th and 5th row in Data_sif match the second row in Data_cam and I want to add the "Discard" here to and so forth for all rows.
The value in the "Discard"-column should be repeated onto every value displayed in the "Size_class"-column for the common timestamp.

The desired output would look like this

```
Data_combined <- data.frame(Start_haul=c(("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  16:11:00")),             VesselID=c('XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX'),Species=("TOR"), Size_class=c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","4","5"),  Landing_kg=c(10.5,20.5,5.6,400,2,120,250,10.3,2.1), 
Discard=c(0.28,0.28,0.28,0.96,0.96,2.92,2.92,2.92,0))
```

I want to add more columns in the final implementation, including positional data, but for simplicity I would like to start with merging the Discard-column.

I have tried old posts but not been able to implement it for the data I have.

Comment: You probably might consider using first e.g. `lubridate` package to round the timestamp and then `left_join` from `dplyr` to join data.frames based on time and id

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `lubridate` and `dplyr`. It's a bit fiddly, but it works:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)


Data_cam <- data.frame(Start_haul=c(("31-10-2015  07:13:00"),("31-10-2015  22:40:00"),("01-11-2015  06:48:00"),("01-11-2015  16:13:00")), 
                       VesselID=c('XBBX','XBBX','XAAX','XAAX'),
                       Species=("TOR"), Discard=c(0.28,0.96,2.92,0)) 

Data_sif <- data.frame(Start_haul=c(("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  16:11:00")),
                   VesselID=c('XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX'),Species=("TOR"), Size_class=c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","4","5"),
                   Landing_kg=c(10.5,20.5,5.6,400,2,120,250,10.3,2.1))



Data_sif %>%left_join(., Data_cam, by = "VesselID",suffix=c('_sif','_cam')) %>%   mutate(buff1 = dmy_hms(Start_haul_cam) - minutes(30)) %>% 
  mutate(buff2 = dmy_hms(Start_haul_cam) + minutes(30)) %>% 
  filter(dmy_hms(Start_haul_sif) >= buff1 & dmy_hms(Start_haul_sif) <= buff2) %>% 
  select(-contains('_cam')) %>% select(-contains('buff'))


# Start_haul_sif VesselID Species_sif Size_class Landing_kg Discard
# 1 31-10-2015  07:05:00     XBBX         TOR          1       10.5    0.28
# 2 31-10-2015  07:05:00     XBBX         TOR          2       20.5    0.28
# 3 31-10-2015  07:05:00     XBBX         TOR          3        5.6    0.28
# 4 31-10-2015  23:05:00     XBBX         TOR          4      400.0    0.96
# 5 31-10-2015  23:05:00     XBBX         TOR          5        2.0    0.96
# 6 01-11-2015  06:28:00     XAAX         TOR          1      120.0    2.92
# 7 01-11-2015  06:28:00     XAAX         TOR          2      250.0    2.92
# 8 01-11-2015  06:28:00     XAAX         TOR          4       10.3    2.92
# 9 01-11-2015  16:11:00     XAAX         TOR          5        2.1    0.00
```

**Edit:**

Or a bit slimmed down:

```
Data_sif %>%
  left_join(., Data_cam, by = "VesselID",suffix=c('_sif','_cam')) %>%
  filter(dmy_hms(Start_haul_sif) >= dmy_hms(Start_haul_cam) - minutes(30) & 
         dmy_hms(Start_haul_sif) <= dmy_hms(Start_haul_cam) + minutes(30)) %>% 
  select(-contains('_cam'))
```

Comment: That works nicely on the data. 
However, I have some trouble transferring this solutions straight onto the full datasets. Probably some datagaps or something. Seems like the sqldf solution suggested by MKR works around that issue though.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be achieved using `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)

# First convert Start_haul  to Date/time
Data_cam$Start_haul <- as.POSIXct(Data_cam$Start_haul, 
          format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

Data_sif$Start_haul <- as.POSIXct(Data_sif$Start_haul, 
      format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

# The absolute difference between Start_haul is considered as less than
#  30*60 (1800 seconds) for joining.     

sqldf("SELECT Data_sif.Start_haul, Data_sif.VesselID, Data_sif.Species,
       Data_sif.Size_class, Data_sif.Landing_kg, Data_cam.Discard
       FROM Data_sif, Data_cam
       WHERE Data_sif.VesselID = Data_cam.VesselID AND
       Data_sif.Species = Data_cam.Species AND
       abs(Data_sif.Start_haul - Data_cam.Start_haul) <= 30*60
      ")

# Result 
#           Start_haul VesselID Species Size_class Landing_kg Discard
#1 31-10-2015  07:05:00     XBBX     TOR          1       10.5    0.28
#2 31-10-2015  07:05:00     XBBX     TOR          2       20.5    0.28
#3 31-10-2015  07:05:00     XBBX     TOR          3        5.6    0.28
#4 31-10-2015  23:05:00     XBBX     TOR          4      400.0    0.96
#5 31-10-2015  23:05:00     XBBX     TOR          5        2.0    0.96
#6 01-11-2015  06:28:00     XAAX     TOR          1      120.0    2.92
#7 01-11-2015  06:28:00     XAAX     TOR          2      250.0    2.92
#8 01-11-2015  06:28:00     XAAX     TOR          4       10.3    2.92
#9 01-11-2015  16:11:00     XAAX     TOR          5        2.1    0.00
```

**Data**

```
Data_cam <- data.frame(Start_haul=c(("31-10-2015  07:13:00"),("31-10-2015  22:40:00"),("01-11-2015  06:48:00"),("01-11-2015  16:13:00")), 
                       VesselID=c('XBBX','XBBX','XAAX','XAAX'),
                       Species=("TOR"), Discard=c(0.28,0.96,2.92,0)) 

Data_sif <- data.frame(Start_haul=c(("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  07:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("31-10-2015  23:05:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  06:28:00"),("01-11-2015  16:11:00")),             VesselID=c('XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XBBX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX','XAAX'),Species=("TOR"), Size_class=c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","4","5"),  Landing_kg=c(10.5,20.5,5.6,400,2,120,250,10.3,2.1))
```

Comment: That works nicely on the dummy data and seems like it works on the full dataset directly too. Have to do some checks to be certain. Thank you for the help

Comment: @ltkrisp Happy to help. It will work on real data too. Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the non-equi joins from data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data_cam)
setDT(Data_sif)

#convert to POSIX datetime and create the 30mins buffer before and after Start_haul
Data_cam[, Start_haul := as.POSIXct(Start_haul, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")][,
    c("BufferStart", "BufferEnd") := .(Start_haul - 30*60, Start_haul + 30*60)]
Data_sif[, Start_haul := as.POSIXct(Start_haul, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")]

#look up the Discard column using non-equi join from data.table package
Data_sif[Data_cam, Discard:=Discard, 
    on=.(VesselID, Species, Start_haul >= Start_haul, Start_haul <= BufferEnd)]
```